# Kendo UI (jQuery) export Excel not working for Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, export-to-excel

I am trying to use [Export Excel](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/export/excel-export?_ga=2.220222352.929456194.1585741994-1809540144.1585741994) feature from KendoUI in jQuery. It works for IE and Chrome but not for Microsoft Edge.

Is it issue with KendoUI library or with browser compatibility?

Note that I am using KendoUI 2015.

Comment: Have you looked in https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues ? Any reasons to use such an old version?

Comment: Can't find an issue regarding Microsoft edge.Client project dumped this abomination

Comment: Is there any error message? Can you reproduce the issue on a runnable Dojo?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is in older Kendo UI versions, It has been fixed in recent releases.

Check this [link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/excel-export-not-working-on-microsoft-edge).